# How to install old version of rust-src?

Tags: rust

My machine have rust nightly-2020-03-24, I want to compile cross-compile crate core. But the command `rustup component add rust-src` install newest version of rust-src, which rustc-2020-03-24 can't build (due to new feature llvm-asm). How can I install old version of rust-src?

Comment: `rustup install stable` if you haven't done it already, then `rustup +stable component add rust-src`

Comment: I'm using rustc nightly, not stable

Comment: IDK how long old nightly versions are kept, but `rustup +nightly-2020-03-24 component add rust-src` should work if it was kept. If it wasn't, then update to the latest nightly or fall back to stable

Comment: It's appear that cargo xbuild tries to pull newest rust-src from github, no matter what rust-src is installed. I'll open issue in their github page.

Answer (score 0):

If not already installed, you can get a specific version of a component by specifying the toolchain when calling `rustup` (like `+stable`, `+1.44`, etc). In your case:

```
rustup +nightly-2020-03-24 component add rust-src
```

The source can then be found in `~/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2020-03-24-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/`.